# Partial ordering on Natural numbers

Tags: number-theory, relations

[image]

Preparing for exams, and came across this past year question. Any ideas?

I know that for partial order, it must be reflexive, transitive and anti-symmetric, but how exactly do i show this?

Comment: Next step is to recall what those terms actually mean. Can you show at least some of them? (one of them should be completely trivial).

Comment: reflexive means a<=a so in this case, since x=y, we can say that the relation is reflexive, coz x=y is effectively saying a<=a

Comment: Great (though you would probably want to phrase it a bit more precisely on a test). What about the other two?

Comment: is it antisymmetric for the same reason. So anti-symm means, if a<=b and b<=a, then a=b. So if x<=y, and y<=x, x=y (which is what we were told)

Comment: Not quite. $x\leq y$ might be because $x=y$ but it could also be because $3x\leq y$, so you need to account for this.

Comment: i know transitive means, if a<=b, b<=c, then a<=c.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft sorry, i don't quite understand :/ the 3x<=y bit confuses me.

Comment: Right, it was a poor choice of me to use the same symbol both for the new relation and the usual order. So if $x\preceq y$ and $y\preceq x$ but $x\neq y$ what would this mean (using the definition of $\preceq$)?

Comment: That...it's not a partial order coz it's not anti-symmetric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- reflexive: You've done it.
- anti-symmetric: let's see what happens if $x \preceq y$, $y \preceq x$, but $x\neq y$ : we have $3x \le y$ and $3y \le x$, so $9x \le x$, so $x=y=0$, impossible
- transitive: if $x \preceq y$ and $y \preceq z$, and x!=y and y!=z (otherwise the relation is trivial), then $3x \le y$ and $3y \le z$ so $(3x \le) 9x \le z$ , $3x \le z$ so $x \preceq z$

Comment: Hey @Baconaro thanks heaps! Just a bit confused as to how you got the x=y=0 bit for anti-sym

Comment: @Azza you have $9x \le x$ so $x=0$ and $3y \le x$